# Consolidar macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Eu necessito de criar uma macro que me possibilite escolher todos os ficheiros .xml e os importe para o excel.
Neste momento o processo é o seguinte:
- Abro o primeiro manualmente e depois chamo a macro que importa todos os outros selecionados.
Queria saber como posso efectuar todos estes passos apenas com uma macro.

```
Sub Import1()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim instance As XPath
Dim Map As XmlMap
Dim XPath As String

ChDir "C:\rwindows"
With ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("evs_rpb_Mapa")
    .ShowImportExportValidationErrors = False
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .PreserveColumnFilter = True
    .PreserveNumberFormatting = True
    .AppendOnImport = True
 End With

fileToOpen = Application _
.GetOpenFilename("XML Files (*.xml), *.xml", , "Import XML", , True)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If IsArray(fileToOpen) Then
    For Each fil In fileToOpen



    ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("evs_rpb_Mapa").Import URL:=fil

    Next fil
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Os meus conhecimentos são nenhuns. Se alguém puder ajudar agradecia.
Obrigado.

Comment: Já vai á algum tempo e não obtive nenhuma resposta. Se alguém souber como posso contornar esta situação agradecia.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui esta um trecho do código que uso para fazer basicamente o que você quer:

1. Abre uma janela de seleção
2. Usuario seleciona uma planilha
3. Excel abre a planilha selecionada, copia os dados e fecha a planilha selecionada.

Observe que eu restringi que o usuario seleciona apenas um arquivo em `.AllowMultiSelect = False`, mas você pode habilitar isso e salvar todos os nomes numa array e repetir o processo de importação num `for`.

```
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

       With fd
      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      .Title = "Selecione a planilha de NFs."

      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Excel 2016", "*.xls"
      .Filters.Add "Todos os arquivos", "*.*"

      If .Show = True Then
        txtFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
      Else
        Exit Sub
      End If
     End With

    Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook

    Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(txtFileName)
    Set Source_Workbook = ThisWorkbook

    LRow = LCell(Target_Workbook.Sheets(1)).Row
    LCol = LCell(Target_Workbook.Sheets(1)).Column

    For i = 1 To LRow
        For d = 1 To LCol

            Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells((3 + i), d)
            Source_Workbook.Sheets(3).Cells((1 + i), d) = Target_Data

        Next d
    Next i

    Source_Workbook.Save
    Target_Workbook.Save
    Target_Workbook.Close False
```